# Check string from single cell for match with any string from a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cell A1 contains a long text string. Cells B1:B6 contain various, shorter text strings.

I want to return TRUE if *any* of the strings from B1:B6 appear *anywhere* in the text string in A1, and FALSE if none appear.

`=COUNTIF(B1:B6,A1)>0` returns TRUE if there is an exact match between A1 and any cell in B1:B6, but FALSE in the case of partial matches (which should also return TRUE).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B1:B6&"*",A1,0)))`

Comment: Try: `=OR(1-ISERR(SEARCH(B1:B6,A1)))`

Comment: Both solutions work, thanks!

I'll be happy to mark one of you correct if you post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above one could use one of the followings:

By **[Ron Rosenfeld](https://superuser.com/users/366681/ron-rosenfeld)** Sir:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B1:B6&"*",A1,0)))
```

---

Or the one posted by me:

```
=OR(1-ISERR(SEARCH(B1:B6,A1)))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @foolishgrunt no issues at all, glad it worked for you. =)